# Understanding a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem when trying to understand the way the number of combinations can be found in this problem:

> Three boys and three girls are to sit on a bench for a photograph. Find the number of ways this can be done if the three girls must sit apart.

Since the question before that asked to find `the number of ways this can be done if the three girls must sit together`, I thought that this value, which turns out to be $144 = 4!\times 3!$, should be somehow used in this question too.

So my approach is to, instead of finding the number of ways the girls can sit apart, I take the total number of was the three boys and three girls can sit, $6!$, and subtract the number of ways the girls should not sit.

The problem I have is to find the number of ways they can cannot sit **or** the number of ways they can sit so that they sit apart.

Some of my workings:

$$\{ab_1b_2b_3g_3\} \qquad a= \{g_1g_2\} \qquad \implies 6!-5!\times2!=480$$

The answer is:

> Finding more than one position that the girls can sit (M1) 
>   Counting exactly four positions (A1) 
>   number of ways = 
>   $4\times 3!\times 3! =144$

Comment: Does "the three girls must sit apart" mean that there can't be any two of them sitting next to each other? Or is this allowed? I think not. In the latter case I agree with the result $144$, but I don't see why you need a subtraction to get it. In the former one just subtract your previous result from $6!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well take that there are $4!$ combinations when $ag_3$ are together(take $n=\{ag_3\}$ so $\{nb_1b_2b_3\}$ has 4! permutations,so the number of exactly two girls together is $5!-4!=96$.Now you can take 2 girls in 3 ways $\{g_1g_2\},\{g_1g_3\},\{g_2g_3\}$ now the number of combinations so that there are exactly two girls together is $3*(5!*2!-96)$ and there are $4!*3!=144$ combinations with exactly 3 girls sitting together now $6!-3*(5!*2!-96)-144=144$ is the number of combinations when girls are setting apart(we substracted the number of all girls sitting together and exactly two girls sitting together)